# What's the purpose of the extra () at the end of an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, anonymous-function

For context: right now I'm adding a temporary conditional statement around a subtitle inside a return statement for a react component. It's just a quick fix for until I add back in a new list of subtitles

What's the purpose of that extra () after the unnamed function? This block of code doesn't work without it and I forgot why

Sorry if this is a simple question but I just read through the javascript docs and didn't see anything talking about this

```
return(
   <div>
        other stuff  blah blah blah

        {(() => {
             if (subtitleId !== 'two') {
                  return (
                       <P key={subtitleId} />
                  );
             }
        })( this right here )}
   </div>
)
```

Comment: That means "define an anonymous function and call it immediately". It's an OK way to define a conditional without using the ternary operator in JSX.

Comment: This is an IIFE. You can read about IFFE here 
https://rahuulmiishra.medium.com/iife-in-javascript-e4a83d06bdd

Comment: awesome tysm guys